# How to connect to ElasticSearch with Java transport client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am following the ElasticSearch documentation on Java Client. I have started ElasticSearch and I can interact with it with the Rest API. I want to use the Java Client and so far I have a main like this:

```
public class TestElastic {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
        JSONObject place = new JSONObject();
        place.put("name", "AAAAA");
        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("my_database", "places", "1")
                .setSource(place)
                .get();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        // Index name
        String _index = response.getIndex();
        System.out.println(_index);
        // Type name
        String _type = response.getType();
        System.out.println(_type);
        // Document ID (generated or not)
        String _id = response.getId();
        System.out.println(_id);
        // Version (if it's the first time you index this document, you will get: 1)
        long _version = response.getVersion();
        System.out.println(_version);
        // isCreated() is true if the document is a new one, false if it has been updated
        boolean created = response.isCreated();
        System.out.println(created);
        client.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

In the Java logs I can see that there is a connection with 127.0.0.1:9300. But after the "prepare index" command I do not see any error and nothing is printed(I have some system out commands). In the ElasticSearch logs is also nothing relative. When I create an index with the Rest API I can see this in the logs.

Comment: can you add `ex.printStackTrace();` in the catch block so we can see if there's an exception? you're swallowing it silently ;-)

Comment: you are right. How could I miss this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as @Val mentioned I forgot to print the errors. The problem was that JSONObject is not the format that ElasticSearch wants. Map and HashMap are acceptable.